# Хочу создать кнопку при нажатии которой выйдет изображение/фото

Tags: java, android

Здесь я сделал кнопку чтоб при нажатии на нее играла музыка. Сейчас я бы хотел чтоб эта кнопка выполняла бы две функции (выведение фото при нажатии на кнопку

P.S2 вроде сделал вот это, думаю код должен работать, но наверное я ошибся с путями указаниями картинки, так как все работает, но при нажатии на кнопку нет картины, только музыка, подскажите пожалуйста в чем моя ошибка тут и как ее исправить. Функцию вызвал, но приложение теперь просто закрывается при нажатии на кнопку.

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickme);
    imgDisplay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_display);
    imgDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    handleVisibilityImageView();
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
}


private void handleVisibilityImageView(){

    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        imgDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        imgDisplay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Не прикладывайте код скриншотом - в таком виде его нельзя скопировать и написать ответ на основе вашего кода. Т.к. скопировать не выйдет - вот вам словесное описание необходимого кода: создайте ImageView в коде и в разметке. Проинициализируйте его в коде. В слушателе нажатия - поместите туда картинку вызовом метода типа `setImageResource(R.id.image)`

Comment: Спасибо понял, отредактировал вопрос добавил код, можете пожалуйста подробнее написать желательно с кодом (я новичок)

Comment: Времени свободного у меня не очень много - код написать не смогу. Но могу помочь советом. Начтите с того, что добавить в разметку ImageView. Приложите в вопрос разметку с этим ImageView (тоже текстом, не скриншотом). После этого добавьте картинку в папку `res/drawable`, добавив в вопрос скриншот структуры проекта, где видно эту добавленную картинку.Потом создайте и инициализируйте переменную для ImageView в вашей активити, аналогично тому, как вы это для кнопки делаете.Обновите код в вопросе с этими изменениями. После этого вам останется только вызвать на ImageView метод из первого комментария

Comment: не нужно упорно добавлять в вопрос скриншот, он никому не нужен

Comment: метод handleVisibilityImageView нигде не используется, поэтому фактически ничего не делает. Сам по себе он выполняться не будет, надо его где-то вызвать.